# How can I attach CIDER's debugger to a Luminus web application?

Tags: debugging, clojure, cider, luminus

I have a Luminus project with the server running on `localhost:7000`. I use `cider-connect` to attach myself to this repl, but I'm met with the following wall:

```
; CIDER 0.10.0snapshot (package: 20150820.852) \
    (Java 1.7.0_51, Clojure 1.7.0, nREPL 0.2.10)
WARNING: The following required nREPL ops are not supported: 
apropos classpath complete eldoc format-code format-edn info inspect-pop \
    inspect-push inspect-refresh macroexpand ns-list ns-vars ns-path refresh \
    resource stacktrace toggle-trace-var toggle-trace-ns undef
Please, install (or update) cider-nrepl 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT and restart CIDER
```

I would imagine at least one of these is required for debugging; attempts to instrument a function yield

```
clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: \
    No reader function for tag dbg
```

---

I can debug just fine with a 'normal' Clojure project.  I've tried adding the boilerplate that normally goes in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` to the project's `project.clj` to no effect:

```
:profiles/dev {:dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10"]]
               :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0-SNAPSHOT"]]}
```

How can I attach CIDER's debugger to this web application?

Comment: I'm not sure about cider, but have you seen this:  http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/deployment.md#enabling_nrepl

Comment: @Ballpark Oh, I actually figured this one out! I forgot that's what this question was about. I'll self-answer tonight.

Comment: @SeanAllred I'd like to see that answer

Comment: @SeanAllred It would be good to post that answer here so other people who eventually have similar problem can solve it.

Comment: @foki alas – I always seem to be making promises on here that I don't keep when it comes to self-answering. I've added a todo item, but the list is long. See https://gitter.im/clojure-emacs/cider?at=55d8c4dfb6d887d9704d21f5 in the meantime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the interest of saving time of people who have similar issue I'll post summary here as an answer.
Thanks to Benedek Fazekas from `clojure-emacs/refactor-nrepl`'s gitter and Sean Allred.

---

To attach `Cider` to `Luminus` application (and probably any other application which uses embedded `nrepl server` as an opportunity of connecting to it while it's running) you should do two things:

- Provide all desired middleware as `:handler` to `clojure.tools.nrepl.server/start-server`. To do this you should have libraries which contain middleware listed somewhere where `lein` can find them (e.g. in `project.clj` `:dependencies`).
- Run application which launches embedded `nrepl server` and connect `Cider` to it using `cider-connect`.

Beside `cider-nrepl` I want to use `refactor-nrepl` which is needed by [Clojure refactor](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el). With example project from [Luminus website](https://luminusweb.com/docs/guestbook) first thing can be done like this:

```
(ns guestbook.core
  (:require [guestbook.handler :refer [app init destroy]]
            [immutant.web :as immutant]
            [guestbook.db.migrations :as migrations]
            [clojure.tools.nrepl.server :as nrepl]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]
            [cider.nrepl :refer [cider-middleware]]
            [refactor-nrepl middleware])
  (:gen-class)) 

    ...

(defn cider&cljr-nrepl-handler []
      (apply nrepl/default-handler (cons #'refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor
                                   (map resolve cider-middleware))))
        
(defn start-app
  "e.g. lein run 3000"
  [[port]]
  (let [port (http-port port)]
    (.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. stop-app))
    (when-let [repl-port (env :nrepl-port)]
      (repl/start {:port (parse-port repl-port)
                   :handler (cider&cljr-nrepl-handler)}))
    (http/start {:handler app
                 :init    init
                 :port    port})))
```

Then you can run your `Luminus` app with `lein run` and connect it with `Cider` using `cider-connect`(`M-x cider-connect` or `C-c M-c`), by default url to connect is `localhost:7000`.

---

Presumably, embedded `nrepl server` in `Luminus` is intended to be used when application is already deployed somewhere and you want to do some live debugging.
For local development there is standard way:

- run `lein repl` in the project root. `Cider` will do the job with `lein repl :headless` on `cider-jack-in`(`C-c M-j`).
- it should launch `repl` in `yourapp.core` namespace where you can run `(http/start {:port 3000 :init init :handler app})` and enjoy! In this case we don't need embedded `nrepl server`. To stop http server run `(http/stop destroy)`. It is described [here](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/repl.md#starting_the_application_from_the_repl).

Comment: Thanks a ton for writing this up :-)